# Extend Discriminated Unions

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

is it possible to do transform this DU using mappend/conditional types

```
type MyDU =
| {kind: 'foo'}
| {kind: 'bar'}

type Transformed = DUTransformer<MyDU>
```

such that we get the folllowing result

```
type Transformed =
| {kind: 'foo', foo: boolean}
| {kind: 'bar', bar: boolean}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because TypeScript will [distribute mapped types over a union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type MyDU =
| {kind: 'foo'}
| {kind: 'bar'}

type Kinded<T extends string> = { kind: T }

type DUTransformer<T> = T extends Kinded<infer K> ? T & {[K1 in K]: boolean} : never

type Transformed = DUTransformer<MyDU>
```

The type of `Transformed` is:

```js
type Transformed = ({
    kind: 'foo';
} & {
    foo: boolean;
}) | ({
    kind: 'bar';
} & {
    bar: boolean;
})
```

Comment: Holy macro! Thx.
could you maybe explain what your DUTransformer does? especially the `Kinded<infer K>` part?

Comment: Think of types as a Prolog statement (and if you don't know Prolog, take a look at [*The Dialog Programming Manual*](https://www.linusakesson.net/dialog/docs/index.html) to learn by intuition how it works.

Comment: But the key is that we're saying `if T extends Kinded<any> then store the argument to Kinded in K and then generate a type which is the intersection of T and the mapped type with all the keys in K associated with booleans`